# How to get previous element from click target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have this html code:

```
<div class="row newrow">
        <div class="col-10"><b>this</b></div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="close.png" id="exit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on img with id exit using this code

```
$('body').on('click','#exit',function(e){
```

})

I need to get the text of the `<b>`behind it which would be `"this"`

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
$('body').on('click','#exit',function(e){    
 $q = $(e.target).prev('b')
       var word = $q.text()
)}
```

It only gives me the  that I clicked from the beginning

Comment: you should use parent().sibling();

Comment: Are you really forced to rely on such a fixed layout? That will get hard to maintain, when someone will want to insert a simple new feature in this markup, your code will get broken. Can't you make it more explicit, e.g by adding data-attributes either to link each elements together or even to add this text's value directly to your img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('body').on('click','#exit',function(e){    
   var this_b = $(this).parent().prev().children(0).html();// get the text
   alert(this_b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).closest('.row').find('b')`:

```js
$('#exit').click(function(e){   
  $q = $(this).closest('.row').find('b');
  var word = $q.text();
  console.log(word);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row newrow">
  <div class="col-10"><b>this</b></div>
  <div class="col-2">
      <img src="close.png" id="exit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the *parent* of the clicked `img` to get the the `.col-2`, and then get the `col-2`'s `prev()` to get to the `.col-10`, and *then* you can access its `children()` to get the children (the single `<b>`). Also, there's no need for `e.target` if you use `this`:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#exit', function() {
  $q = $(this).parent().prev().children();
  var word = $q.text()
  console.log(word);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row newrow">
  <div class="col-10"><b>this</b></div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="close.png" id="exit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').on('click','#exit',function(e){    
 var word = $(this).closest('.newrow').find('b').text();
 });
```